# laravel 6 - how to add new object in get all records

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

[image]
[image]

**Postman return response**

[image]

I need to add an array field after "transaction_type": null, "repay": true

**if "payment_status": payment_pending**

Comment: Try to use Resources it will help you https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources

Answer (score 0):

loop on `$getAllOrders`

```php
    $outputOrders = [];
        foreach ($getAllOrders as $order){
            $order['repay'] = $order['payment_status']=="payment_pending";
            $outputOrders = $order;
        }
```

then you can return the array `$outputOrders` instead of `getAllOrders`

Comment: just do it in the same way to $getAllOrders['data']